# Appending multiple values to dictionary appends "None"

Tags: python-3.x

I try to add a list to a dictionary key, but when I append a value, it returns the value `None`. I have also tried `collections.defaultdict(list)` without success.

Code:

```
text = "ABBBAACCCCAABBCCCCAABCBCBCABCCCA"
chain = dict()

for i in range (0, text.__len__()-1):
    key = text[i : i+1]
    next_word = text[i +1 : i +2]

    if key not in chain.keys():
        chain.setdefault(key)
    else:
        chain.setdefault(key, [].append(next_word))

    print(key, next_word, chain[key], chain)
```

Output:

```
A B None {'A': None}
B B None {'B': None, 'A': None}
B B None {'B': None, 'A': None}
B A None {'B': None, 'A': None}
…
```

Comment: `[].append(next_word)` returns `None`, not the list.

Comment: Also, you do **not** need `if key not in chain.keys()` when using `setdefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[].append()` returns `None`. You'd want to append to the *return value of `dict.setdefault()` instead*. You also don't need to do a key containment test when using `dict.setdefault()`; `setdefault()` *already* makes that test for you.

Next, don't call `object.__len__()`. Use `len(object)` instead. I'd also use `{}` instead of `dict()`; the latter has to look up a name and make a function call, the `{}` literal is compiled to a single bytecode to create a dictionary.

This works:

```
for i in range(len(text) - 1):
    key = text[i:i + 1]
    next_word = text[i + 1:i + 2]

    chain.setdefault(key, []).append(next_word)
```

You could also use `zip()` to pair up the letters:

```
for key, next_word in zip(text, text[1:]):
    chain.setdefault(key, []).append(next_word)
```

Demo:

```
>>> text = "ABBBAACCCCAABBCCCCAABCBCBCABCCCA"
>>> chain = {}
>>> for key, next_word in zip(text, text[1:]):
...     chain.setdefault(key, []).append(next_word)
...
>>> chain
{'A': ['B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'B': ['B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'C': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A']}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(chain)
{'A': ['B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
 'B': ['B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
 'C': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A']}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, my error was to check if the key existed. Because it existed, it returned None and did not add anything to the list?

Comment: @ET333: no, the `list.append()` method returns `None`, because the list is updated in place. Note that I used `chain.setdefault(..., []).append(...)`, where you used `chain.setdefault(..., [].append(...))`. Pay close attention to where the parentheses are.